# cannot connect remotely with online database on localhost phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i have configured the phpmyadmin's config.inc.php file and a drop down menu has appeared accordingly in localhost/phpmyadmin to select the server. But when i try to connect to the server it says:
 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
 i have added my ip address to the online host server in the cpanel and have access to the remote sql connection.
please help.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "have access to the remote sql connection"? You cannot have "access" to a connection. I suggest you check if you can connect to the sql server from the system your phpmyadmin application is executed on. That way you can make sure that 1. you do have network access and 2. your credentials work.

Answer (score 0):

Most hosts block incoming connections to the MySQL server as a security measure. You'll have to ask your host about unblocking port 3306 and how to access your MySQL directly -- or run an API on your web host, which would have access to the MySQL server due to being on the same network, and access the database through that. For phpMyAdmin specifically, just install it on your web host instead of your local machine, then access it through the internet rather than localhost.